# Using clang static analyzer on windows

Tags: windows, clang

I've seen a couple of similar questions but they are based on building clang from sources.

Today I can just download pre-build clang for Windows and it will just work (well, sort of). According to manual I should be able to just substitute call to make with a call to scan-build.bat and that's it.

I found scan-build.bat in clang/bin directory and here it is:

```
perl -S scan-build %*
```

As far as I can see it should start some perl script named scan-build but I can't find it anywhere in clang directory or even clang sources.
And now I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

It's under `llvm\tools\clang\tools\scan-build\bin`.

Comment: I downloaded the latest available build for windows (3.8.0 64bit) and I don't have llvm\tools\clang folder.. There is just llvm\tools\msbuild. I just installed 32bit version and there is no llvm\tools\clang folder either.

Comment: Ah, I missed that you said you downloaded the the pre-built version.  I clone the repos and build my own.  Perhaps it's inadvertently omitted from the pre-built versions.